# network card disabled upon reboot

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

Every time I start my windows 7 laptop (Asus x550lb), the network appears with a red x on it and is not able to search for wifi signals.

Each time I boot my computer I need to go to device manager, uninstall the network driver (but not remove it). Then scan for hardware changes at which point the network adapter is identified and driver is installed and is now able to search for available wifi signals. Now I re-enter my wifi credentials and the card works. I need to do this every time and remember the credentials of all networks I attempt to connect to.

I have a second drive with ubuntu on it and the card works fine. I also swapped my main hard drive with one containing windows 10 and again it works fine si the problem has to be with windows. I tried rollback to a date when I know that the card worked fine, bios upgrade, an older driver, looking through similar problems in microsoft support forums and still I have no clue as to what even can cause this problem in the first place.

What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is likely due to a hardware button/switch that tells the OS that its state is disabled. Using device manager overrides that, but that state is reset on each boot.  Find the button, press it, and see if that solves the issue. If not, then reinstall the wifi card.

Comment: @LPChip Interesting! The hardware button on my laptop is the f2 key used in conjunction with the fn key but testing it right not it does not seem to work at all even though other buttons (volume up and down, brihtness etc) do. Will investigate.

Comment: @LPChip Wow... Reinstalling the keyboard drivers activated the remaining fn keys. The keyboard is the last place I would look for a networking problem... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. :) Yes, have had several of these problems with customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post you an answer, so you can let others know you no longer need help.

Based on your description, it seems likely that the WiFi software disables the WiFi due to the "hardware state" of wifi, which can be toggled on and off either by a hardware button or a keyboard combination, such as <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (it may be a different keyboard combination depending on the laptop).

If changing the state of the hardware button has no effect, then you need to reinstall the wifi software or keyboard drivers.